# mobile HTML5 plugin to display long text

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a term-of-service page in my mobile HTML5 application. The term of service is about 60k in size. What I want is fitting the long text within the whole display and the user can scroll to view the whole text. Is there any plugin for this purpose?

I use canvas to display short text but I don't think it's a good idea to display term of service. I am not sure if I can use textarea to do this with proper settings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an iframe that loads a separate .html file containing the TOS text. This way it will be easy to manage the content by just editing the TOS file, and easy to style the page since the iframe comes with scrollbars, you just need to set the width and height.

```
<iframe src="TOS.html" ></iframe>
```